# DKIM-запись в Exim4 не работает

Tags: ubuntu, exim4

На сервере установил Exim4, перечитал сотню мануалов, но письма всё равно отправляются в спам - не проходит проверку DKIM.

Ubuntu 16.04, Exim4.
Создание ключей:
Cоздаем папку dkim в которой будут лежать ключи:

```
sudo mkdir /etc/exim4/dkim
```

Перходим в созданную директорию dkim:

```
cd /etc/exim4/dkim
```

Генерация секретного ключа.
Повторить этот шаг для каждого доменного имени.
sudo openssl genrsa -out domain.ru.key 1024
Генерация открытого ключа путем извлечения из секретного ключа.
Повторите этот шаг для каждого доменного имени.
(Команда `openssl rsa -in domain.ru.key -pubout > domain.ru.pub` не сработала, недостаточно прав даже с судо, работает когда папке присваиваю пользователя под которым зашёл, поэтому использовал команду ниже)

```
sudo openssl rsa -in domain.ru.key -pubout
```

Результат отобразится на экране, копирую публичный ключ для каждого домена.
Установить разрешения:

```
sudo chown -R Debian-exim:Debian-exim /etc/exim4/dkim/
sudo chmod 640 /etc/exim4/dkim/*
```

Не забудьте повторить процесс создания секретных и открытых ключей для каждого из ваших доменных имен.
Теперь откройте /etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template.

```
sudo nano /etc/exim4/exim4.conf.template
```

Найти секцию: remote_smtp:
Выше этой строки добавить:

```
DKIM_DOMAIN = ${lc:${domain:$h_from:}}
DKIM_FILE = /etc/exim4/dkim/${lc:${domain:$h_from:}}.key
DKIM_PRIVATE_KEY = ${if exists{DKIM_FILE}{DKIM_FILE}{0}}
DKIM_SELECTOR = mail
DKIM_CANON = relaxed
remote_smtp:
dkim_domain = DKIM_DOMAIN
dkim_selector = DKIM_SELECTOR
dkim_private_key = DKIM_PRIVATE_KEY
dkim_canon = DKIM_CANON
```

Перезапустить Exim4:

```
sudo systemctl restart exim4.service
```

---

Создаём TXT в DNS записях доменов.
Необходимо создать поддомен для DKIM с селектором mail:
mail._domainkey.domain.ru
Далее создать TXT-запись:

```
v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIGfMA0GCSq...
```

Для проверки отсылаю письмо с сервера:

```
echo "This is a test." | mail -s Testing user@gmail.com
```

Итог: все письма попадают в спам.

Дополнительная команда:

```
exim -bP transports | grep dkim
dkim_canon =
dkim_domain = ${lc:${domain:$h_from:}}
dkim_private_key = ${if exists{/etc/exim4/dkim/${lc:${domain:$h_from:}}.key}{/et c/exim4/dkim/${lc:${domain:$h_from:}}.key}{0}}
dkim_selector = mail
dkim_sign_headers =
dkim_strict =
dkim_canon =
dkim_domain =
dkim_private_key =
dkim_selector =
dkim_sign_headers =
dkim_strict =
```

Письмо из спама gmail:

```
Delivered-To: user@gmail.com
Received: by 10.64.236.15 with SMTP id uq15csp164924iec;
        Wed, 30 Nov 2016 06:08:13 -0800 (PST)
X-Received: by 10.25.211.3 with SMTP id k3mr12464379lfg.133.1480514893134;
        Wed, 30 Nov 2016 06:08:13 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <flame@server.domain.com>
Received: from server.domain.com (server.domain.com. [123.123.123.123])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id j79si31845777lfj.85.2016.11.30.06.08.12
        for <user@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Wed, 30 Nov 2016 06:08:12 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of flame@server.domain.com designates 123.123.123.123 as permitted sender) client-ip=123.123.123.123;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@server.domain.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of flame@server.domain.com designates 123.123.123.123 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=flame@server.domain.com
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=server.domain.com; s=mail; h=From:Message-Id:Subject:To:Date; bh=Hy61WwSEndqwKzArKPLZcQPACoRjmbmRdNbnqGWeg+Y=; b=ogOwmorVSs9ulo6v1jAlQ54yjV JNkdOuWkk016K8L3SH8Sr6GRwOSja85uKoNozkMD79H5gkljI5Or53LXXbcOmYfxl/CTcYgqHqN47 6HPJhGeGLGpFFKatrzxj/P9zxr0VrYVf4VYYQ94kZHwjtu4p3rBD/rjQvpiIBSENfEKY=;
Received: from flame by server.domain.com with local (Exim 4.86_2) (envelope-from <flame@server.domain.com>) id 1cC5YS-0008TU-2s for user@gmail.com; Wed, 30 Nov 2016 17:08:12 +0300
Date: Wed, 30 Nov 2016 17:08:12 +0300
To: user@gmail.com
Subject: Testing
User-Agent: s-nail v14.8.6
Message-Id: <E1cC5YS-0008TU-2s@server.domain.com>
From: flame@server.domain.com

This is a test.
```

Comment: строки, начиная с `remote_smtp:` (включая и её), явно лишние. а вообще, конечно, в первую очередь надо смотреть на заголовки пришедшего письма.

Comment: Дело в том, что перечитал много мануалов и везде пишут вставить эти строки. Доменов несколько.

Comment: две секции `remote_smtp` в конфигурационном файле **точно** не нужны. а оставшиеся строки, если вы заглянете в текущую конфигурацию, просто излишни: там уже есть все эти присвоения (в секции `remote_smtp`).

Comment: вот здесь, например, таких рекомендаций, про которые вы говорите, нет: https://debian-administration.org/article/718/DKIM-signing_outgoing_mail_with_exim4 // потому что руководство уже ориентировано на debian-овскую сборку exim-а (которую ubuntu-вцы стараются не сильно ломать).

Comment: кстати, а зачем вам вообще этот dkim «сдался»? насколько я знаю, его наличие/отсутствие/корректность/некорректность оказывают столь малое влияние на спам-оценку, что им можно смело пренебречь. если требуется криптографическое подтверждение авторства письма, по-моему, лучше использовать что-нибудь типа gpg (самими отправителями, а не smtp-сервером, естественно).

Comment: и, кстати, насколько я помню, обновления конфигурации дистрибутивного exim-а (которая сохраняется отндюь не в `/etc`) при рестарте не производится. это нужно явно делать. см. хотя бы в приведённой мною выше ссылке.

Comment: Проходил тесты, и письма идут в спам из-за неверной подписи DKIM. Он однозначно нужен. Ну вот по вашей ссылке где для мультидоменов написано, всё в точности как у меня. Кстати эту статью тоже изучал, уже не знаю, что делать с этим Exim4...

Comment: *письма идут в спам из-за неверной подписи DKIM* — по-моему, это отличный повод забыть про dkim.

Comment: *dkim=pass* — возможно, я чего-то не понимаю в гугловских почтовых заголовках, но, [вроде бы, это говорит о том, что dkim есть и успешно проверен](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_authentication#Authentication-Results).